# Google Indexa Codigo de AngularJS al imprimir Json

Tags: json, angularjs, seo

Al momento de buscar mi sitio en google, este indexa cierto código de angular y lo muestra en los resultados

[image: Codigo de angular en resultados de google]

en mi index.html imprimo la información de Json de esta manera

```
<li><a href="vehiculos.html">{{ common.nav.vehicles }}</a></li>
<li><a href="Empresas.html">{{ common.nav.copanies }}</a></li>
<li><a href="contactos.html">{{ common.nav.contacts }}</a></li>
```

Se hace de esa manera ya que el sitio es multiidioma.

Comment: Si posteas mas código para entender mejor tu problema.

Comment: Para entender mejor tu problema podrías mostrar el archivo que esta indexando *Google* o cuando menos donde tienes el atributo `ng-app="..."`.

Answer (score 0):

Me parece que el problema se debe a que estás mostrando los datos en sin compilar (*raw, uncompiled*) antes de que estén preparados posiblemente porque realizas llamadas asíncronas a tu back-end.

Para resolver esto es necesario añadir la directiva `ng-cloak` en las vistas que desees que no tengan este comportamiento.

Aquí una explicación de la directiva: (*traducción*)

> La directiva ngCloak se usa para evitar que el navegador muestre
>   brevemente la plantilla html de AngularJS en su forma original (sin
>   compilar) mientras se carga la aplicación. Utilice esta directiva para
>   evitar el efecto de parpadeo no deseado causado por la visualización
>   de la plantilla html.
>
> La directiva se puede aplicar al elemento, pero el uso preferido es
>   aplicar múltiples directivas ngCloak a pequeñas porciones de la página
>   para permitir la representación progresiva de la vista del navegador.

#### Referencias

[`ngCloak`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngCloak)